# Porting Eigen3 library for Chrome's Portable Native Client (PNaCl) build error

Tags: c++, opencv, google-nativeclient, eigen3

So I have an AWS instance (the free tier one) running with Ubuntu 16.04. There I have installed nacl_sdk (which is working and has allowed me to access their sample sites with success) and naclports which I used to port opencv with which I had trouble with at first due to errors with zlib but got it working after I added i386 architecture and did sudo apt-get update on the system and installed necessary i386 programs.

Note I have depot_tools installed as well.

Now I am trying to install the eigen3 library for pnacl as well but I am getting an error and I am not sure how to understand it nor how exactly it gets built to fix it.

The command that I ported opencv with was

```
$ NACL_ARCH=pnacl make opencv
```

And I tried these two commands for building eigen3 with the same results (shown below)

```
$ NACL_ARCH=pnacl make eigen3
$ bin/webports install eigen3
```

This is the very end of terminal output (the entire message is very long):

```
######################################################################
Building eigen3
######################################################################
chdir /home/ubuntu/Work/ExternCode/naclports/src/out/build/eigen3/build_pnacl
make -j1 basicstuff cholesky determinant geo_transformations inverse
Scanning dependencies of target basicstuff
Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/basicstuff.dir/basicstuff.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable basicstuff
Built target basicstuff
Scanning dependencies of target cholesky
[100%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/cholesky.dir/cholesky.cpp.o
clang: error: unable to execute command: Killed
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
clang version 3.7.0 (https://chromium.googlesource.com/a/native_client/pnacl-clang.git cf0dc7f6e6123dfa9b8834b56743315300b34e6c) (https://chromium.googlesource.com/a/native_client/pnacl-llvm.git baa63524b6b493ec2a6aa2c5193d9f25c0c33191)
Target: le32-unknown-nacl
Thread model: posix
clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://llvm.org/bugs/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang: note: diagnostic msg: 

test/CMakeFiles/cholesky.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'test/CMakeFiles/cholesky.dir/cholesky.cpp.o' failed
make[3]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/cholesky.dir/cholesky.cpp.o] Error 254
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:14386: recipe for target 'test/CMakeFiles/cholesky.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/cholesky.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:14393: recipe for target 'test/CMakeFiles/cholesky.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/cholesky.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:5128: recipe for target 'cholesky' failed
make: *** [cholesky] Error 2
webports: Build failed: 'eigen3' [pnacl/release]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `clang: error: unable to execute command: Killed`

It looks like your AWS instance killed clang, so perhaps it ran out of memory. The free tier gives [1 MiB](https://aws.amazon.com/free/faqs/) of RAM and that might not be enough for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Not sure if I was supposed to know that (if so sorry for stupid question) but you're totally right, I added swap space to the ec2 instance and it's working. Thank you!